# Hibernate Spatial: Type org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType

Tags: java, hibernate, spatial

I'm using Hibernate Spatial version 4.0-M1. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/tutorial-hs4.html). However, my code fails with the following error: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType, at #table_name# for column #geometry_column#`.

My session factory creation class is as shown below:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

After digging around for a possible cause, I've found out that it has something to do with my configuration. My `hibernate.cfg.xml` is as shown below:

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName</property>
    <property name="connection.username">dbUsername</property>
    <property name="connection.password">dbPassword</property>

    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.testapp.model.EntityClassWithAnnotations" />

</session-factory>
```

Any idea on what I may be doing wrong will be appreciated very much.

**UPDATE:** My entity class is shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class MyEntityClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "gid")
    private Long gid;

    @Column(name = "adm1_name")
    private String  adminName;

    @Column(name = "adm1_code")
    private String adminCode;

    @Column(name = "pmal")
    private Double pmale;

    @Column(name = "pfem")
    private Double pfemale;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
    @Column(name = "the_geom", nullable = true)
    private Geometry geom;

    public MyEntityClass() {}

    public Long getGid() {
        return gid;
    }

    public void setGid(Long gid) {
        this.gid = gid;
    }

    public String getAdminName() {
        return adminName;
    }

    public void setAdmin_name(String adminName) {
        this.adminName = adminName;
    }

    public String getAdminCode() {
        return adminCode;
    }

    public void setAdmin_code(String adminCode) {
        this.adminCode = adminCode;
    }

    public Double getPmale() {
        return pmale;
    }

    public void setPmale(Double pmale) {
        this.pmale = pmale;
    }

    public Double getPfemale() {
        return pfemale;
    }

    public void setPfemale(Double pfemale) {
        this.pfemale = pfemale;
    }

    public Geometry getGeom() {
        return geom;
    }

    public void setGeom(Geometry geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**: I think I see the error in your hibernate.cfg file, you are using wrong dialect.

replace your dialect row with:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
```

Comment: My mapping is shown above. I'm using annotations. I'm updating my code to include my entity class. As for the database, I'm using it with other applications, mainly openlayers. So, I don't think the problem is with my database.

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo. Changing the dialect seems to have no effect. It could be something else, not the dialect.

Comment: Well, your maping is ok, your dialect is ok, your db is ok so it must be the query? I dont think so, I would review The Hibernate/JPA Configuration acording to tutorial one more time http://www.hibernatespatial.org/tutorial-hs4.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `hibernate-spatial.jar` was missing which includes `org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType`.

We're using maven and the old 1.1.1 version of hibernate spatial so after I added the following to the pom, all was well:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernatespatial</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```